# How to transform a Map[Symbol, List[A]] to a List[Map[Symbol,A]] in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I need to convert a

```
Map[Symbol, List[A]] to a List[Map[Symbol,A]]
```

but I cannot find a compact snippet of code to do it (I suppose there is a very compact way to achieve this).

Specifically, I have a

```
Map('a -> List("aa", "bb", "cc"),
    'b -> List("dd", "ee", "ff"),
    'c -> List("gg", "hh", "ii"))
```

and I want to get a

```
List(Map('a -> "aa", 'b -> "dd", 'c -> "gg"),
    (Map('a -> "bb", 'b -> "ee", 'c -> "hh"),
    (Map('a -> "cc", 'b -> "ff", 'c -> "ii"))
```

Notice that all the Lists in the first collection are of the same size.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala> val m = Map('a -> List(1,2), 'b -> List(2,3,4))
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,List[Int]] = Map('a -> List(1, 2),
                                                          'b -> List(2, 3, 4))

scala> m.flatMap { case (k,l) => l.map(x => Map(k -> x)) }.toList
res2: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Int]] = 
      List(Map('a -> 1), Map('a -> 2), Map('b -> 2), Map('b -> 3), Map('b -> 4))
```

**Updated answer :**

```
scala> m.map {case (k,l) => l.map(x => (k,x))}.transpose.map(_.toMap).toList
res4: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,String]] =
      List(Map('a -> aa, 'b -> dd, 'c -> gg),
           Map('a -> bb, 'b -> ee, 'c -> hh),
           Map('a -> cc, 'b -> ff, 'c -> ii))
```

Comment: I realized I was not clear in explaining what I need. I added further details and an example

Answer (score 2):

For

```
val a = Map('a -> List("aa", "bb", "cc"),
            'b -> List("dd", "ee", "ff"),
            'c -> List("gg", "hh", "ii"))
```

an approach with `zip`,

```
a.values.transpose.map { vs => (a.keys zip vs).toMap }
```

Pretty much the approach already suggested, perhaps slightly more idiomatic/succinct.